How to have a SwiftUI Shape View conform to dimensions of a neighboring view
Simple Explanation:
I am displayed a SwiftUI Capsule() to display a status color next to a Text() view. In all cases so far the capsule is used inside an HStack with the Text view.
I would like to have the height of the Capsule to match the height of the text. This has not been a problem in some situations, such as in a List(). In other cases, however, the capsule view will take up more vertical space than the text.
Additional Complexities
I have wrapped the Capsule() view into a custom view called StatusCapsule() to allow me to take a color and width parameter to adjust more easily. I have tested with just the Capsule() view and experienced the same outcomes.
In my problematic view, the HStack is placed within a GridRow(), within a Grid(), within a ScrollView(), within a NavigationStack().
My confusion also comes from that my first and second GridRow() views both had this issue, however, after placing the Grid() in a ScrollView(), the top GridRow() output StatusCapsule() views to my expectation, but the second GridRow() did not.
Below is the code for the StatusCapsule View and a simplified AnalyticsView() view, as well as a screenshot of the results of the code
StatusCapsule() View:
struct StatusCapsule: View {
    
    var color: Color = .white
    var width: CGFloat = 4
    
    var body: some View {
        Capsule()
            .fill(color)
            .frame(width: width)
    }
}

Problematic view with grid and scroll views:
I replaced all dynamic code in the Text views and color parameter fields with static values to simply the code. I did test this simplified code and received the same result as my dynamic view, so to my understanding the two are fundamentally the same.
struct AnalyticsView: View {
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    @State private var nums: [String] = ["5","9","4","7","33","37","81"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            ScrollView {
                Grid(alignment: .center, horizontalSpacing: 5, verticalSpacing: 5) {
                    GridRow(alignment: .center) {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                .foregroundStyle(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                                .padding(2)
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    StatusCapsule(color: .cyan)
                                    StatusCapsule(color: .cyan)
                                    Text("Total Expected: $1,350.65")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                }
                                HStack {
                                    StatusCapsule(color: .cyan)
                                    Text("Total Completed: $25.44")
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                    Text("|")
                                        .bold()
                                    StatusCapsule(color: .blue)
                                    Text("Total Invoiced: 45.67")
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                }
                            }
                            .padding()
                        }.gridCellColumns(2)
                    } // Headline Cell
                    GridRow() {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                .foregroundStyle(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                                .padding(2)
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("In Progress: 5").font(.headline)
                                ForEach(nums.prefix(5), id: \.self) { num in
                                    HStack {
                                        StatusCapsule(color: .red)
                                        Text("\(num)")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .padding(.vertical)
                            .scaledToFit()
                        }.gridCellColumns(1)
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                .foregroundStyle(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                                .padding(2)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Analytics")
        }
    }
}

I have been looking into controlling the frame of views and have not found a solution I'm satisfied with other than delving deep into UI code from before SwiftUI. I would like the capsule view to dynamically conform to the height of the text view in its associated HStack.
I'm expecting the result I see in the first row of the grid, and I'm also confused as to why I'm seeing different results between the two rows once placed in the ScrollView. In regards to this, the capsules in the top GridRow acted exactly as they do in the second GridRow when the entire Grid was not placed in the ScrollView

Explanation
The reason why the capsule would sometimes take up more vertical space than the text is because a Capsule, like all shapes, is greedy. It will normally use as much space as possible.
Forcing ideal size as a way to fix
One way to fix is to force the containers to adopt their ideal vertical size by applying a .fixedSize modifier, as explained in another answer by Sweeper. Putting the content inside a (vertical) ScrollView has the same effect, see also How to use ideal size for HStack and VStack layout, instead of max size.
However, setting .fixedSize might have side effects on other content. In particular, if you have any Spacer, Divider, other shapes or colors then these might not expand as you would like them to. The RoundedRectangle in the cells of your Grid are cases in point.
Using an overlay to fix
Another way to fix is to apply the StatusCapsule as an overlay to the Text:

an overlay is automatically constrained by the size of the content it is applied to (btw, the same applies for a background layer too)
use alignment: .leading to keep the overlay left-aligned
add leading padding to the Text to make space for the overlay; the size of the padding should corespond to the width of the bar + spacing (previously, the spacing was provided by the HStack).

Text("The quick brown fox\njumps over the lazy dog")
    .padding(.leading, 12)
    .overlay(alignment: .leading) { StatusCapsule(color: .cyan) }


More concise code
As the example above illustrates, if you just want to add a status bar to a single Text item then an HStack is no longer needed to combine them. You could also consider adding a View extension to apply the modifiers:
private extension View {
    func statusCapsule(color: Color) -> some View {
        self
            .padding(.leading, 12)
            .overlay(alignment: .leading) { StatusCapsule(color: color) }
    }
}

This makes it possible to apply a status capsule in a concise way to any text (or in fact, to any view), with the added benefit that the spacing will always be consistent. Here is how the top VStack of your example could be adapted to use this approach:
VStack {
    Text("Total Expected: $1,350.65")
        .font(.headline)
        .statusCapsule(color: .cyan)
        .statusCapsule(color: .cyan)
    HStack {
        Text("Total Completed: $25.44")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .statusCapsule(color: .cyan)
        Text("|")
            .bold()
        Text("Total Invoiced: 45.67")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .statusCapsule(color: .blue)
    }
}



I am a big fan of the more concise code.
I can see a few places in my code where I’d rather use that.
Is there any consensus or documentation on when to prefer this method? I could see using this for the grid cell backgrounds as well, however I don’t know if there’s any benefit or drawbacks of doing that is this method as well

@tishly Pleased to have been able to help, thanks for accepting the answer! Yes, when you want to have a shape like a rounded rectangle (or even an image) in the background then it is very often better to apply it using .background, instead of as the first layer in a ZStack. This way, it automatically adopts the size of the foreground content and doesn't affect the sizing of the container. So in your example, if you just want the cells to have sizes that ideally fit their contents, apply the rounded rectangles as background to the VStack, after the padding.

Your answer was very detailed and I think the .overlay() method will improve my code legibility a lot. Happy to learn that.
In reference to using the .background(), which would be better than my idea of creating another extension func: Will the background still conform to its GridRow() neighbors when placed in a Grid()? I suppose in this layout they will fill the view by default, which will still act Greedy if the neighboring view is larger?

@tishly In the case of the grid cells, if the content of adjacent cells might have different heights but you want the backgrounds to have the same heights, you could indeed use a view extension to apply .frame(maxHeight: .infinity) to each container, followed by a background layer with a rounded rectangle. But you will still need to apply .fixedSize to either the grid row or the grid as a whole, to reduce the height of the cells to the minimum necessary. It would at least be a slightly more concise way of applying the background than using a ZStack in each cell.

I just got a chance to implement the code you shared and noticed I had an issue implementing the statusCapsule extension because of the private tag. Removing that allowed me to use it as you displayed in your reply

@tishly Yes, if the extension is only needed in 1 source file then you can define it as private in the same file. But if you plan to use it more widely then you can remove the private access restriction. This makes it available to all your source files. You could also say, it exposes it to all source files.

Your desired behaviour is the default behaviour in a grid cell in a scroll view, but the capsules are stretched because the VStack is scaledToFit. You should remove that.
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("In Progress: 5").font(.headline)
    ForEach(nums.prefix(5), id: \.self) { num in
        HStack {
            StatusCapsule(color: .red)
            Text("\(num)")
        }
    }
}
.padding(.vertical)
//.scaledToFit() // <---- remove this

Output:

The ScrollView "fixes" the first grid row because the scroll view prevents its contents from expanding to fill all the available space (after all, there is "infinite space" in a scroll view). The contents of a scroll view will be sized according to their ideal sizes, which you can also do with the fixedSize modifier. So if you don't actually need a ScrollView, you can do
Grid {
    // ...
}
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

You can also do this to the HStack containing the Shape and Text.
HStack {
    StatusCapsule(color: .red)
    Text("\(num)")
}
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

Since StatusCapsule does not have a fixed size but Text does, StatusCapsule will be resized to the ideal size of the Text.

The scaledToFit() snippet was a relic from laying out my RoundedRectangle() before even using the grid… that explains a lot.
In your example, does applying .fixedSize() to the Grid() itself mean the effect trickles down to all the contained sub views? Would that mean applying it to just the HStack prevents it from affecting the RoundedRectangle()?
